# Is it possible to load an entire file from disk efficiently in Scheme R6RS?

Tags: file, scheme, r6rs

The following `get_file` function reads file from disk as a Scheme R6RS string:

```
; Gets all characters from a port
(define (read_chars_from_port_rev port result)
  (let ((char (read-char port)))
    (if (eof-object? char)
      result
      (read_chars_from_port_rev port (cons char result)))))

; Gets the contents of a file as a string
; If it doesn't exist, returns empty
(define (get_file file)
  (if (file-exists? file)
    (let ((port (open-input-file file)))
      (let ((text (list->string (reverse (read_chars_from_port_rev port '())))))
        (begin
          (close-input-port port)
          text)))
    ""))
```

It works by opening the file, tail-call-recursively reading char-by-char into a linked list until we find eof, closing the file, then reversing the linked list (because of the tail-call) and converting it to a string.

This procedure should be slow compared to, say, Node.js's `readFile`, because it reads char by char, and allocates a linked list with one cell for each character in the file. Ideally, we should be able to just read a file as a string buffer, with no dynamic memory allocations.

Is there any way to optimize `get_file` with the primitives available in R6RS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get-string-all`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_sec_8.2.9):

```
> (let* ((fp (open-input-file "my-file.txt"))
         (buf (get-string-all fp)))
    (close-port fp)
    (display buf))
Four score and seven years ago
our fathers brought forth upon this continent,....
```

This can be made somewhat more convenient by using [`call-with-input-file`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_sec_8.3):

```
;;; Returns a string containing the contents of the file `fname`; closes the
;;; input port automatically (unless `get-string-all` does not return for
;;; some reason).
(define (get-file fname)
  (call-with-input-file fname get-string-all))
```

```
> (get-file "my-file.txt")
"Four score and seven years ago\nour fathers brought forth upon this continent,....\n"
```

You can use [`guard`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_7.1) to facilitate returning an empty string when the sought file does not exist (as in the posted code):

```
(define (guarded-get-file fname)
  (guard (con
          ((i/o-file-does-not-exist-error? con) ""))
    (call-with-input-file fname get-string-all)))
```

```
> (guarded-get-file "my-file.txt")
"Four score and seven years ago\nour fathers brought forth upon this continent,....\n"

> (guarded-get-file "oops.txt")
""
```